# Scroll should be on the downside of a particular div when page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery

My current code is like this

```
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <h1>Messages</h1>
    <div style="overflow-y: scroll; height: 325px;" id="content">
        @each('messenger.partials.messages', $thread->messages, 'message')
    </div>
    <hr>
    @include('messenger.partials.form-message')
</div>
```

And The script part is like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function () { 
      window.location.reload();
    }, 60 * 1000);
    window.onunload = function(){ 
        window.scrollTo(0,0);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is when the page reloads or at the beginning, the scroll of the div starts from the top. I want it to stay at the bottom so that the user can see the latest messages. They don't need to scroll down to see the latest messages. In my current code structure, how can I implement that feature?

Answer (score 0):

In your code `@include('messenger.partials.form-message')`, if each message is wrapped by a div or any wrapper then you can use `scrollIntoView`([scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)) to scroll to the last child

```
document.querySelector(".col-sm-8 div:last-child").scrollIntoView()
```

Comment: My messages are on the second div with id content and where i used the scrolling. Now where should I use  document.querySelector("#content div:last-child").scrollIntoView() on the script?

Comment: ok then it should be like `document.querySelector("#content div:last-child").scrollIntoView()`, you can use it after this statement `window.location.reload();` or for manual refresh just on the script tag at the bottom of body

Comment: It doesn't work. I have used this: 
$(document).ready(function () {
     $('div').animate({
         scrollTop: $('#content').offset().top + $('#content').height()
     }, 'slow');
 });

Comment: Then I think, you can simply give it as `$("#content").animate({ scrollTop: $('#content').height() }, 'slow');` inside document ready

Comment: That's more optimum. Thanks @AswinRamesh

Comment: Or using normal JS, you can use like 
`content = document.getElementById("content");
content.scrollTop = content.scrollHeight;`